# drag and drop not working using selenium python headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Recently, I created python script to test web application using Selenium Chrome Webdriver.
Most of the action is done by Selenium Chrome webdriver. However, Drag_and_drop Actionchain is not working in headless mode. Even with headed mode, Drag_and_drop Actionchain is working only when the mouse point is on proper position and I have to move the mouse. And also, I tried drag_and_drop_by_offset but it didn't work neither.

I couldn't find any solution neither answer for this problem.
Anyone has the clue regarding this issue, please help me to work out.

```
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).drag_and_drop(source1, target1).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source1, 50, 50).perform()
```